# How can I make my shell script abort on error?

Tags: bash, shell

For example I have

```
make test
# do other stuff
```

'make test' runs some unit tests and will exit with success or error.  How can I terminate the entire script and display a message if make test aborts with an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
make test || exit $?
```

In the general case, `set -e` forces the script to abort on any error; but this is frequently overkill, as you have to guard against insignificant errors.

Comment: To add an error message, use `make test || { stat=$?; echo "make failed, aborting" >&2; exit $stat; }`

Comment: `make` usually prints an error message of its own, though.  For anything but the most trivial scripts, I usually define `warn` and `die` functions, so you can say `make test || die $? "make failed, aborting"`.

Answer (score 2):

without error message you could simply use

```
set -e
make test
#more stuff
```

if you want to print out the status

```
make test
if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
    echo "all fine!"
else
    echo "yikes, something went wrong"
    exit 1
fi
#more stuff
```

Comment: Why not just `if make test; then ...`?  No need to test `$?` explicitly.

Comment: I think it's more readable this way instead of executing commands within an if block. matter of taste.

Comment: Don't use `set -e`. Heartache follows. Use proper error handling instead.